# Trying to get model list to display in jList1 when program is run

Tags: java, swing, list, user-interface, arraylist

I have an array list with books in, each book has a title, author etc. etc.  The problem that I am having is once turning that array into a model list is then getting that to be display by `jList1` in my GUI when the program is run.

Is what I've done below along the right track?

```
public class BookstoreMainScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {

class Group {

    ArrayList<Object> bookList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    Group() {
        bookList.add(new book("dinosore", "bob", "thus", 40, 310, 34));
    }
}

private DefaultListModel<String> createListModel(ArrayList<String> myListModel) {
    DefaultListModel<String> l = new DefaultListModel<>();
    for (String s : myListModel) {
        l.add(0, s);
    }
    jList1.setModel(createListModel(myListModel));
    return l;
}
```

Edit: My output is a blank list box when I run the program, when what I want is the contents of the `ArrayList` (`bookList`) to be displayed.

Comment: What is your problem? could you edit your post saying what is your output , what is your desired output? where are you having trouble?

Comment: It looks like you've changed your original code in your question so that it does something else. Please don't do that, it's really annoying!

Answer (score 2):

Take a longer look at your code...

`return` means, stop processing commands and exit the method immediately, so anything after the `return` statement will not be executed (with the possible exception of `finally` blocks)

```
private static DefaultListModel<String> createListModel(ArrayList<String> myListModel) {
    DefaultListModel<String> l = new DefaultListModel<>();

    for (String s : myListModel) {
        l.add(0, s);
    }

    // This causes the. Ethos to exit...
    return l;
    // So these lines won't be executed...
    DefaultListModel jList1 = createListModel(myListModel);
    jList1.setModel(myListModel);

}
```

Having said that, if you loved the `return` statement to the end of the method, it will setup a infinite recursive method call which will result in a `StackOverflowExcception`, because you are calling `createListModel` again...

A better soliton would be to remove the last lines from the method and simply apply the model from the same call context...

```
jList1.setModel(createListModel(myListModel));
```

For example...

Comment: So after making those changes would that be everything that needs to be done in order to get the array(bookList) displaying in my list box on my gui? I thought I would have to use a loop or something. I've confused myself over the last few hours on a task I thought would be simple.

Comment: You already have a loop in the createListModel. So long as the reference of jList1 is the same as the one on the screen, then you shouldn't have any issues...

Comment: the list is displaying "Item 1, Item 2" and so on until 5, in the design of the GUI what should be in the "model" field on the properties for the list box. Sorry if im sounding silly.

Comment: Until you run the program is run it shouldn't change, but there isn't enough code in your example to know if anything else is going wrong...